# Qt QTableView row colow

Tags: c++, qt

I am learning Qt and I have some difficulty.
I was using QTableWidget and when an item receive a double click a change row color:

```
for (int j = 0; j < ui->tableWidget->horizontalHeader()->count(); j++) {
    ui->tableWidget->item(row, j)->setForeground(color);
}
```

But now I am using QTableView, I created a QAbstractTableModel to this and work fine. I done some filters with QSortFilterProxyModel and work fine too.
But I am not having success to change row color.
I already tried things like this:

```
m_model.setData(m_model.index(1,2) , QColor(Qt::blue), Qt::BackgroundColorRole);
```

And not work.
In model::setData() I wrote some debugs and it joins in function right, but not change color.

```
bool MyModel::setData(const QModelIndex &index, const QVariant &value, int role)
{
    if (data(index, role) != value) {
        qDebug() << index << value << role;
        emit dataChanged(index, index, QVector<int>() << role);
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Debug output:

```
QModelIndex(1,2,0x0,MyModel(0x7fffffffe408)) QVariant(QColor, QColor(ARGB 1, 0, 0, 1)) 8
```

Comment: Qabstractitemmodel doesn't store any values on its own. You need to store the choice in your setData() impl and return the color for the corresponding index in your data() impl.

Comment: Thank you @FrankOsterfeld, I made it after your suggestion :)

Answer (score 0):

You could use own item delegate, in view constructor call function - setItemDelegate

in delegate reimplement paint function:

```
paint(QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionViewItem &option, const   QModelIndex &index) const
```

get info about geometry from QStyleOptionViewItem,
about content - QModelIndex

some flags to check state, as example:

```
if(option.state & QStyle::State_Selected)
{
        painter->save();
        QPen pen(QColor(30, 144, 255, 255), 2, Qt::SolidLine, Qt::SquareCap, Qt::MiterJoin);
        int w = pen.width()/2;
        auto rect = option.rect;
        rect.setX(0);
        painter->setPen(pen);
        painter->drawRect(rect.adjusted(w,w,-w,-w));
        painter->restore();
}
```

As for double click event - in view re-implement mouseDoubleClickEvent, get index (for example: indexAt(event->pos())) and store some color data, then use that data at delegate's paint function.